# How to do text based filtering on DateTimeFields using a specific template format?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a table that includes both CharFields and DateTimeFields displayed using django template language. The DateTimeFields are displayed in the format "Aug. 18, 2020, 6:33 p.m.". Is there an easy way to do a text based filter/query on the DateTimeFields based on that specific format? For example, searching "aug" or "Aug" or "Aug. 18" or "2020" should find that entry.

I've tried icontains, but that seems to work on the underlying format, rather than the display format. For example, searching "2020-08" finds that entry, but searching "Aug" does not.

Works:

```
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='2020')
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='2020-08')
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='33')
```

Does not work:

```
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='Aug')
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='6:33')
Entry.objects.get(created__icontains='p.m')
```

1. Is there a way to search the using the specific dat time display format?
2. What format is the underlying DateTimeField? Is it DB dependent?

Partial answer for 2: the underlaying format seems to be UTC in the format
"2020-05-12 18:58:23.210862+00". Using icontains on any of that text works.

For clarification, the idea is to search all fields (datetime and string) with the same text. So, "Aug" should return a row that has a date field with "Aug 13" or a string field with "Augustine". Kind of like a general google search.

Answer (score 1):

you have change string to datetime,
like this:`date = datetime.date(2020, 8, 3)` ,
here is you can use:

- date:`Entry.objects.filter(created__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))`
- year:`Entry.objects.filter(created__year= 2020)`
- month:`Entry.objects.filter(created__month=8)`
- hour:`Event.objects.filter(created__hour=6)`
- minute:`Event.objects.filter(created__minute=29)`
- second:`Event.objects.filter(created__second=31)`

you can see more about date querysets on here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#year

Comment: Thanks. Undertstood that this is one approach. But this question is if it can be done using pure text on the display format. The idea is to search all fields (datetime and string) with the same text. So, "Aug" should return a row that has a date field with "Aug 13" or a string field with "Augustine". Kind of like a general google search.

Comment: sorry, my English is pretty basic,  you can't use text to search all fields,  you have to choose the date type.